# Parse HTML table in C# and save in Array

Tags: c#, string-parsing

I have an HTML page that can contain many tables. Some tables can be placed inside of another tables. I need a C# code to automatically read and parse all the existing table data and save them into array list, excluding table header values.

Here is my code so far, using `HtmlAgilityPack`:

```
    string strFilepath = @"filepath\index.html";
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFilepath))
    {
        lblValues.Text = "exists";
        //
        HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlDocument();
        hdoc.LoadHtml(strFilepath);
        List<List<string>> table = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").Descendants("tr").Skip(1)
            .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
            .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
            .ToList();
        //
    }
    else
    { lblValues.Text = "error"; }
```

File path is correct, but it gives me an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Also how to separate those tables that are within other tables?

**EDIT:**

```
    <table>
        <thead><tr><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th></tr></thead>
        <tr><td>value01</td><td>value02</td><td>value03</td></tr>
        <tr><td>value11</td><td>value12</td><td>value13</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: The error means that your code assumes something isn't going to be `null` when in fact it is `null`.  So... Which object is `null`?

Comment: Maybe some of the tables have a tbody and therefore selecting tr as descendant of table results in null? Also, your code is not very robust, you skip the first row hard-coded assuming it's a header row so you're not accounting for empty tables.

Comment: I edited my question and added my table. All the cells have a value.